# Fantasy book set in medieval times, in which one of the characters wields a double-sided battleaxe

Tags: story-identification, books, medieval

I am looking for a fantasy book from the '80s or '90s, set in medieval times, with very graphic battle scenes which include one of the main characters wielding a double-sided battleaxe that cuts an enemy in half at the top of a castle wall.

The scene that I most remember, about the enemy being cut in half, continues to describe how the top half falls but the bottom half stays, and they are still connected by the intestines, causing the top half to bounce up and down like a bungee cord.

I believe the author of the book was David Eddings.

Comment: Can you recall any further details about the characters or plot? This isn't much to go on.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. If no correct answer has been posted, this is a good time to [edit] more details in, especially if some answers don't match details you didn't think to add.

Comment: When I saw the title, I immediately thought 'David Eddings'. He has a fondness for double sided double axes. So much so this is all that I remember of whatever book of his I read.

Answer (score 21):

You might be thinking of *[The Sapphire Rose](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/291356.The_Sapphire_Rose) (1992)* by David Eddings, the third book in his *[Elenium](https://www.goodreads.com/series/43710-the-elenium)* series.

According to this [TV Tropes article](https://allthetropes.fandom.com/wiki/An_Axe_to_Grind), it features a character called [Ulath](https://davideddings.fandom.com/wiki/Ulath), who wields:

> a double-headed axe

And there's [a scene on page 189 of the book](https://archive.org/details/sapphirerose002/page/188/mode/2up) that is very similar to what you described:

> One Rendor, quite skinny and waving a rusty saber, stood howling before the man in black armor bearing down on him. Sparhawk altered his swing slightly and sheared the man almost in two at the waist. The Rendor was hurled against the battlements by the force of the blow, and the remaining shred of flesh ripped as the upper torso toppled outward. The man's lower half caught up on one of the battlements, the legs threshing wildly. The Rendor's upper torso did not quite reach the ground below, but hung head downward from a long rope of purple bowel that steamed in the cool night air. The torso swung slowly back and forth, jerking slightly downward as its intestines gradually unravelled.

[image]

Comment: If this answer is correct, please upvote it and accept it by clicking on the check mark just beneath the voting arrows.